How to properly validate user session with `aws-amplify/auth`?
Description
I've web project hosted on AWS Amplify. In this project, there are a login and sign up screen which are using the aws-amplify/auth to handle my user authentication. Since I've created the screens from scratch I am not using the Authenticator component from aws-amplify, only the enabled methods (signIn, signUp, etc).
This is my auth flow:

User access the platform
I use the fetchAuthSession method in order to check my user's session
If the fetchAuthSession returns a object which the tokens are empty, I redirect my user to the auth routes
If the fetchAuthSession returns the auth tokens, my user can access the application

Doubts/Concerns
Is fetchAuthSession enough to throw an error if my user's session is no longer valid, or something like that?
I've seen plenty of discussions around this, but I'm still not sure.
I saw people talking about using the amazon-cognito-identity-js lib in order to have more flexibility on the user's authentication, but I want to keep using aws-amplify/auth for it's simplicity.
